# Quick measure that sums a column, is grouped by another and doesn't change if filters are selected (DAX)

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have a table in Power BI named 'Dati Popolazione ATTR'.

```
Comune   | Attributo    | Valore

Town1    | A1           | 10

Town1    | A1           | 10

Town1    | A2           | 20

Town2    | A1           | 5

Town2    | A1           | 5

Town2    | A2           | 10
```

What I want is to create a quick measure that sums 'Valore', is grouped by 'Comune' and doesn't change if filters are selected on the sheet. So what I expect as an output is:

```
Comune   | Attributo    | Valore   | Measure

Town1    | A1           | 10       | 40

Town1    | A1           | 10       | 40

Town1    | A2           | 20       | 40

Town2    | A1           | 5        | 20

Town2    | A1           | 5        | 20 

Town2    | A2           | 10       | 20
```

Measure is not supposed to vary if any filter is selected though...

So far I got to this point:

```
Measure = SUMX ( ALL('Dati Popolazione ATTR'), 'Dati Popolazione ATTR'[Valore])
```

Values doesn't change if filters are selected. However it is not grouped.
Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct measure:

```
Measure = 
CALCULATE( 
    SUM( 'Dati Popolazione ATTR'[Valore] ), 
    ALLEXCEPT( 'Dati Popolazione ATTR', 'Dati Popolazione ATTR'[Comune] )
)
```

This is the result:

[image]

However you won't be able to create the expected table because power bi group all rows that have the same data. So the first 2 rows will be grouped and you will only be able to see 1 row in your final table. In order to solve this problem you should add an id column and add that new column to the table.

Comment: You saved my day. Thank you so much!